# Reflection set field value in constructor

Tags: java, reflection

I want to serialize my conguration files and want to use default values if the value not defined in the file so all values are inialized with values. The problem ist that I can't override these "default values" with reflection in the constructor.

```
public class SerializedConig {

    public SerializedConig(String value) {
        Field field;
        try {
            field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("field");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleConfig extends SerializedConig {

    private String field;

    public ExampleConfig(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I can't override these "default values" with reflection in the constructor` You should tell something more about it. Do you get any error or you just don't see results where they should be?

Comment: Can we know why you want to declare your `String field` in subclass as `private`? If it will move this field to `SerializedConig` and declare it as `protected` (as Russell suggested) access to it will have only your subclass and classes from same package as `SerializedConig`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scoping problem. You are passing the value into the super() constructor, but the field value in the superclass is not a class variable, it's a local variable. The field value in the sub-class is global, but not getting set by the super() constructor due to this. You can't override it because they are two different instances that just happen to have the same name.

I'm not sure why you're using reflection here, though I think I can see what you're aiming at, this could just as easily be handled through normal assignment.

You could try the following:

```
public class SerializedConig {

    protected String field;

    public SerializedConig(String value) {
        try {
            field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("field");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleConfig extends SerializedConig {  
    public ExampleConfig(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection here was used to be able to have access any `String field` in subclass of `SerializedConig`. Also local variable `Field field` is seemed to be used correctly here because it is just helper variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this and it is working. Where I am differing from you? Only added one IllegalArgumentException and a main method.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;

class SerializedConig {

    public SerializedConig(String value) {
        Field field;
        try {
            field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField("field");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, value);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Configuration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class ExampleConfig extends SerializedConig {

    private String field;

    public ExampleConfig(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleConfig e = new ExampleConfig("s");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```